# Calcular la media de los valores positivos y negativos

Tags: python, python-3.x

me podrian ayudar con este otro ejercicio he intentado definir el promedio , pero no logro conectar y diferenciar los positivos de los negativos, si me ayudaran se los agradeceria, muchas gracias,

.Realizar un programa que lea N números enteros por teclado. Calcular y mostrar la media de los valores positivos y la de los valores negativos de los N valores leídos. Se debe validar que los números sean valores positivos.

```
suma=0
i=0
x=int(input("Cantidad de numeros a evaluar: "))
aux=x
while x>i:
    n1=float(input("Intro dato: "))
if n1 < 0 :
    print ("hay un valor negativo")
else:

 suma+=n1
 x-=1

media=suma/aux
print("La media es: ", media)
```

Answer (score 2):

La condición de ese `while` se cumple siempre, estarás pidiendo datos indefinidamente, deberías utilizar un contador `i+=1`.

Así como realizar la `suma+=n1` dentro del `while`, de lo contrario sólo promediarás el último número.

Te piden que hagas la media de números positivos y negativos, yo lo separaría en dos listas y calcularía la media al final:

```
suma=0
i=0
x=int(input("Cantidad de numeros a evaluar: "))
aux=x
positivos=[]
negativos=[]
while x>i:
    n1=float(input("Intro dato: "))
    i+=1
    if n1<0:
        negativos.append(n1)    
    else:
        positivos.append(n1)

if len(positivos):
    print("La media de positivos es: ", sum(positivos) / len(positivos))
if len(negativos):
    print("La media de negativos es: ", sum(negativos) / len(negativos))

input()
```

No intentes hacer el ejercicio completo, vete paso a paso, comprobando cada resultado que vas obteniendo: empieza por el bucle, luego comparas con cero y, ya al final, calculas la media... si intentas codificarlo todo junto, lo normal es que no te salga, y ni siquiera sepas por dónde empezar a buscar errores. No te desanimes y continúa, todos hemos empezado alguna vez.

Comment: Muchas gracias , por tu consejo amigo , de verdad te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)